# I've got enabled Hyper-V, but can't install Windows Phone 8.1 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

I've got:

- Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro (64bit, Russian language) on a laptop
- 6GB RAM
- Core i5 with Hyper-V support
- Hyper-V enabled in BIOS and I can create virtual machines through Hyper-V manager
- Visual Studio 2013 (Update 2/Russian language)

And I can't install Windows Phone 8.1 emulator. I checked Hyper-V settings by CoreInfo and I've got "Hypervisor is present (-)". I tried Damir tip (http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2012/10/14/windows8-error-hypervisor-is-not-running.aspx), but in bcdedit I've got hypervisorlaunchtype set to auto.

Does anyone know, what also I should check except the checklist (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524.aspx)?

I've already used Windows Phone 8.0 emulator on my laptop about year ago. Since that time I changed only HDD (to hybrid HDD) and reinstalled everything.

---

Error message from installer.

On English: Your computer doesn't support Windows Phone emulator for which you need a 64bit Windows 8.1 Pro and a computer with Hyper-V support. See additional information here go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394063

Original: Этот компьютер не поддерживает эмулятор Windows Phone, для которого требуется 64-разрядный выпуск Windows 8.1 Pro и компьютер, поддерживающий Hyper-V. Дополнительные сведения см. по адресу http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394063

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: @OlivierPayen, yes. Something like 'Your computer doesn't support Windows Phone emulator for which you need a 64bit Windows 8.1 Pro and a computer with Hyper-V support. See additional information  here http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394063'. I added error message to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your system supports Hyper-V through this simple tool:

If yes, then tel me. let me give an easy way to activate emulator on your PC.

To check BIOS settings for SLAT by using the MachineSLATStatusCheck tool from Codeplex

Download and run the following tool from Codeplex. This tool has a simple graphical user interface.

Download [MachineSLATStatusCheck](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=271819)

Comment: My hardware supports SLAT. "let me give an easy way to activate emulator on your PC." I've already activated Hyper-V in BIOS. I can manage Virtual Machines in Hyper-V. What do you mean by activating an emulator?